# mysql correlated subquery count to return only if count >0

Tags: mysql, correlated-subquery

I simply want to get results if Count>0 from the following mysql query.

The following gives results even if Count=0.

```
SELECT id, Name, 
(
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM 
(
%actual count query here%
) A WHERE C.id=A.matching_col
) AS Count
FROM t1 C 
WHERE id!=0
ORDER BY Name
```

I change "`WHERE id!=0 AND C.Count!=0" or "WHERE id!=0 AND t1.Count!=0"`, but it says '`Count is an unknown column`'.

How should it be done?

Comment: have you tried "Count != 0" without the "t1."? (and change it to something like k to avoid confusion)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `HAVING Count>0` to the end of your original query.

Since your count column is an alias derived from another query, I don't believe the where clause can use it directly.

Answer (score 1):

I would alias your 2nd query and do the where on it like

```
select * from 
(   
    select count(*) as cnt from (   

        select * from videos
    ) a
) b
where cnt > 0
```